# QT setColumnWidth does not work in qtablewidget

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget, qicon

This is my following code I added an icon to filetable (column 0) but I can't change the width of column 0

```
void Window::showFiles(const QStringList &files)
{
     int row=0 ;

    filesTable->clearContents();

    for (int i = 0; i < files.size(); ++i) {
        QTableWidgetItem *fileNameItem;
        QTableWidgetItem *icon_item = new QTableWidgetItem;//
        QIcon icon("myPATH/3.png");
        icon_item->setIcon(icon);
        QFile file(currentDir.absoluteFilePath(files[i]));
        qint64 size = QFileInfo(file).size();

        fileNameItem = new QTableWidgetItem(files[i]);
        fileNameItem->setFlags(fileNameItem->flags() ^ Qt::ItemIsEditable);


        filesTable->insertRow(i);
        filesTable->setItem(i, 0, icon_item);
        filesTable->setItem(i, 1, fileNameItem);
        filesTable->setColumnWidth(0,1);
        filesTable->resizeColumnsToContents();
        qDebug()<<"-***-"<<filesTable->columnWidth(0)<<endl;
        row++;
        if(filesTable->item(i,1)->text()==fileNameImg){
            filesTable->selectRow(i);
        }

    }
    filesFoundLabel->setText(tr("%1 file(s) found").arg(files.size()) +(" (Double click on a file to open it)"));
    filesFoundLabel->setWordWrap(true);
}
```

but my table view is this:

[image]

Is there any way to reduce distance between icon (item of column 0) and text (item of column 1)?

**UPDATE 1:**

I added `filesTable->resizeColumnsToContents();` to my code, but it does not make a difference, I need to reduce the gap as much as possible

Answer (score 0):

Try resizeColumnToContents(int column) to get them closer.

Answer (score 0):

Merging two tables in one table. So have to fixed the table size and merge in one table.. It can works setColumnWidth on final table.
Sample size i tried here,

```
fileNameItem->resize(100,100);

icon_item->resize(50,100);

filesTable->setColumnWidth(0,100);

filesTable->setColumnWidth(1,50);
```

This try will helps you..